# CloudFormation format error - "YAML not well-formed. (line 249, column 21)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, conditional-statements, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I recently added a resource policy to a stack template which has been applied in our app and when executing it in cloudformation, found error "YAML not well-formed. (line 249, column 21)".

I have marked where line 249 is in below code.

```
ATMDatabaseSecretResourcePolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::SecretsManager::ResourcePolicy'
    Properties:
      BlockPublicPolicy: true
      SecretId: !Ref ATMDatabase
      ResourcePolicy:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Action: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
            Effect: Deny
            Principal: '*'
            Resource: '*'
            Condition:
              'StringNotEquals':
                'aws:principalArn': 
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/DA-Deploy'
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/DA-DEVAdmin'
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/DA-Support'
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/DA-Developer'
                  - !sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${InstanceIdentifier}-LoanMiddlewareRole'        --  line 249
                  - !sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${InstanceIdentifier}-LoanAccountRole'
                  - !sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${InstanceIdentifier}-AuthorizerRole'
                  - !sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${InstanceIdentifier}-AuthenticationRole'
                'aws:sourceVpce':
                  Fn::ImportValue:
                    !Sub '${TargetNetworkStack}-AppsVpcId'
```

It seems I can't have more than 4 aws:principalArns, as if I removed from line 249 to line 252 and only leave the first 4 there, then the error disappear.

I wonder if there is an alternative to get around this issue as I need to set more than 4 values for the condition key.  I checked AWS Document but haven't found resources which mentions a limitation of maximum items for the condition key.

Comment: Never mind, i finally figured out the issue, From line 249 to line line 250, I used '!sub' instead of !Sub, it is a silly mistake which I spent quite a bit time to ...

Comment: Hey also !Ref will likely cause and issue as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused, because you have `!sub`, rather then `!Sub`. CloudFormation is case-sensitive.

Comment: yes, later I found it.